# How to debug Emacs lisp that makes Emacs crash/use 100% CPU?

Tags: emacs, elisp

There's an external library I'm working with that frequently pegs my CPU. I'd like to help the author fix it (as I really like the library), but I don't know how to debug the crash properly.

Any tips for debugging Emacs lisp? Bear in mind when it crashes Emacs doesn't work anymore and I have to kill it (so solutions within Emacs itself might not be helpful).

**Edit**: I should clarify that it is byte-compiled, and this issue doesn't always happen for others, so it may be specific to my architecture/init files. It is definitely related to this library though.

Comment: If it's not an infinite loop but just some really complicated code, have you considered trying to byte-compile it before using?

Comment: It is byte-compiled. Thanks though!

Comment: I'm not good with backtraces, and I suspect you aren't, either, but attaching with a debugger and printing a trace could help narrow the search somewhat. Other than that, sprinkle the code with debug prints ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, always debug the uncompiled version of a Emacs-Lisp program, unless you're convinced the problem is introduced by the byte-compiler.

Second, if the code is hanging Emacs then the code is probably in an infinite loop with inhibit-quit bound non-nil.  So the first thing to do is go through the source for the library and change all inhibit-quit references to something else so that C-g will work to stop the looping.  After that, load up the library, set debug-on-quit to t and you should get a nice debug trace when you press C-g that shows you where the code is looping.  From there, debugging the problem should be as straightforward as debugging any other infinite loop.

Comment: The problem with using it non-compiled is that it's basically unusable due to its performance. I'll see if there are any `inhibit-on-quit` calls in the codebase, that's a good call.

Comment: There aren't any `inhibit-on-quit` calls. I'll try the `debug-on-quit` thing.

Comment: inhibit-quit not inhibit-on-quit.  It would typically be bound like this: (let ((inhibit-quit t) ...) ... some code ...)